# Transparency in Hours Text

Tags: css, wordpress

I am working on a development wordpress site here: https://www.tcsdesignreno.com/deanosauto/

The problem is that the hours at the very top of the page are faded out. I tried to change this by adding: `.working-hours {color:rgba(255,255,255,1); !important;}` but it is still faded. Can anyone tell where the opacity is getting changed (if that is it)?

Thanks!

Comment: The `;` character before `!important` is almost certainly causing the immediate problem (that an `!important` rule is being ignored, because of the syntax error). But you have to identify the source of the CSS that's being inherited - by a more specific selector- by the element you're trying to style.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the ';' but still have the faded colors. That is my problem, I can't seem to find the element that the CSS is being inherited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your style.css file is this

```
.working-hours-label {
font-size: 12px;
opacity: 0.5;
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

try changing that and see if that does anything?

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I had to use all the elements mentioned by Michael Coker below.

Answer (score 1):

The text is faded because of CSS `opacity` applied to the text blocks. Remove the `opacity` lines from these 3 classes.

```
.working-hours-label {}
.working-hours-time > span {}
.working-hours-date {}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was part of it!

Answer (score 0):

`opacity: 0.4` (which is applied to that working hours text) is set here:

```
https://www.tcsdesignreno.com/deanosauto/wp-content/themes/autorepair/style.css
```

on line 227, in a rule for `.working-hours-time > span`